# Can't display KendoUI buttons on android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, kendo-ui

I'm having a bad time with the buttons in KendoUI. When I debug with Ripple, I can see the buttons, but when I try on my phone (an Atrix with CyanogenMod7), the buttons just does not show!

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div data-role="view" data-layout="listado-layout" id="main-update" data-title="Actualizar Base de Datos">
<ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
  <li><center><input type="button" onclick="updateDB();" value="Actualizar"></input></center></li>
</ul>
```

By the way, I'm making an application with PhoneGap, and I cannot see the buttons from the browser or phonegap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Android's browser - a button in a transformed element looses its default styling and has only black text on transparent background and looks like it disappears. As a workaround you can use data-role="button" to use the Kendo UI Mobile styling, like this:

```
<li><center><input type="button" data-role="button" onclick="updateDB();" value="Actualizar" /></center></li>
```